# Invalid datetime format for a field never submitted?

Tags: 7, ajax, services, entities

I'm working my the edit page for my mobile app which is fetching data from a Drupal site. I'm fetching data, I'm editing it, and submitting it. However, when submitting back, I'm getting `Internal Server Error : An error occurred (22007): SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2009' for column 'field_yapim_yili_value' at row 1` but I'm not even fetching that field. It's a field collection, if that matters. In fact, I even grep'd my codebase for that field, it doesn't even exist. I checked the content type, it's not required. Any ideas how I can debug this?

UPDATE: Below is what I have in Chrome development tools network tab

```
node[type]:oyuncu
node[title]:Ergün YOLSUZ 
node[language]:und
node[field_tc_kimlik_no][und][0][value]:1737769758
node[field_sgk_durumu][und][value]:devam_ediyor
node[field_kategorisi][und][0]:oyuncu
node[field_kategorisi][und][1]:yardimci_oyuncu
node[field_telefon][und][0][value]:05352107332
node[field_telefon_2][und][0][value]:02122111048
node[field_adres][und][0][value]:Mecidiyeköy mah Şehit Ertuğrul Kabataş Cad. 
node[field_yasadigi_sehir][und][value]:34
node[field_e_posta][und][0][value]:ergun@magicleaves.com
node[field_cinsiyet][und][value]:bay
node[field_gogus][und][value]:75
node[field_bel][und][value]:96
node[field_kalca][und][value]:116
node[field_dogum_tarihi][und][0][value][date]:1 Nis 2016
node[field_boy][und][value]:170
node[field_kilo][und][value]:75
node[field_goz_rengi][und][value]:kkahve
node[field_ten_rengi][und][value]:esmer
node[field_ayak_no][und][value]:46
node[field_egitim_duzeyi][und][value]:Lisans
node[field_oyunculuk_egitimleri][und][0][value]:-
node[field_diller][und][0][value]:Almanca, İngilizce, Türkçe
node[field_beceriler][und][0][value]:Bateri, gitar, piyano, okçuluk, kılıç sanatları, dans, bilgisayar, 
node[field_kisisel][und][0][value]:Çok acayip adamım ben. Cidden bak. 
node[field_videolar][und][0][video_url]:
node[field_videolar][und][0][description]:
node[field_okudum_anladim][und][value]:0
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible your `field_yapim_yili_value` field has a default value and that default value is invalid for datetime format.

Comment: I've just checked, it doesn't have a default value.

Comment: Besides, I'm not even retrieving that.

Comment: by using hook_form_submit check field value in $form_state

Comment: I'm not using any PHP in my mobile app.

Comment: Check it at the PHP end @Kartagis, that's where the error originates. Just because you're not explicitly setting a value for the field doesn't mean Drupal won't be writing to it on your behalf

Comment: What I don't understand it, how come Drupal complains for a field I'm not even fetching, therefore not submitting.